# unknown: Unexpected token (13:9)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

When I compile my Ruby on Rails project I get this error. I am using React for the views.
By the way, if I go to any of my view paths, this error doesn't come up anymore until I recompile my code. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

```
SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (13:9)
  11 | class Our_professionals_accordion extends React.Component{
  12 | 
> 13 |    state = {
     |          ^
  14 |         visible: true,
  15 |         whichComponentToShow: "Accordion",
  16 |         id_user: 0
  17 |            }
```

This is my jsx file

```
class Our_professionals_accordion extends React.Component{

   state = {
        visible: true,
        whichComponentToShow: "Accordion",
        id_user: 0
    };

    professional;


    hide = (id) =>{
        this.setState({whichComponentToShow: "Info"})
        this.professional = this.props.users.find(item => item.id === id);
    }
    render() {

        let data = this.props.users;

        if (this.state.whichComponentToShow === "Accordion") {
            return (
                <div className="Accordion">

                    <Container className="professionals_body">


                        <Accordion >
                            <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
                                <Accordion.Header>Cornea y Segmento Anterior</Accordion.Header>
                                <Accordion.Body>
                                    <Row className="professionals-row">
                                        {Object.entries(data).map(([id, item]) => (
                                            <Col xs={6} md={6} xl={6} key={item.id}>
                                                <button  onClick={() =>  this.hide(item.id)} className="professionals-info-action h-100">
                                                    <div className="professionals-info">
                                                        <img src={item.foto}/>
                                                        <label></label>
                                                        <p>{item.nombre} <b>{item.apellido}</b></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </button>
                                            </Col>
                                        ))}
                                    </Row>
                                </Accordion.Body>
                            </Accordion.Item>                       
                        </Accordion>


                    </Container>
                </div>
            );
        } else if (this.state.whichComponentToShow === "Info") {
            return (
                <div className="App">
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({whichComponentToShow: "Accordion"});
                        }}
                    className="professional-button">
                        Volver
                    </button>
                  <Our_professionals_info professional={this.professional}/>

                </div>
            );
        }

        return null;
    }

}

export default Our_professionals_accordion;`
```

When I compile my Ruby on Rails project I get this error. I am using React for the views.
By the way, if I go to any of my view paths, this error doesn't come up anymore until I recompile my code. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Is your state defined before? You have to use **const state= *...***

Comment: when i use const state, i get "Newline or semicolon expected"